# on hover side nav materialize css

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm using materializecss Side Nav in my project. I'm trying to show the nav bar on hover. Can someone help me with that? 
Below is my code snippet attached.

```
$("nav").hover(function() {
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
});

<div class="navbar">
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a href="#" data-target="slide-out" id="menu" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
            <!-- <a href="#" data-target="slide-out" id="menu_icon" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i> -->
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
    <li>
        <div class="user-view">
            <p class="nav_title">TURBIZO</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nav_list" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav_list" href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav_list highlight" href="contact.html" >Contact</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav_list" href="#!">Carrers</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you included the JQuery file

Comment: can you fiddle on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Material CSS use side-nav instead of sidenav.  [Material CSS Sidenav Reference](http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html)

```
<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
```

Use data-activates instead of data-target.

```
<a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" id="menu" class="sidenav-trigger"><i 
 class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
```

In jquery use .sidenav-trigger instead of .sidenav. Also plugin name is sideNav()

```
$(".sidenav-trigger").sideNav();
```

Here is code snippet for sidenav.

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
   <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" id="menu" class="sidenav-trigger">
   <i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
  </div>
</nav>
<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
 <li>
  <div class="user-view">
  <p class="nav_title">TURBIZO</p>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li><a class="nav_list" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a class="nav_list" href="about.html">About</a></li>
 <li><a class="nav_list highlight" href="contact.html" >Contact</a></li>
 <li><a class="nav_list" href="#!">Carrers</a></li>
</ul>
```

Add jquery.js before the materialize.js. Initialise sideNav plugin first and then change the trigger method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".sidenav-trigger").sideNav();
   $("nav").hover(function () {
     $(".sidenav-trigger").sideNav('show');
   });
});
```

[**On hover SideNav Material CSS**](https://codepen.io/jasjashim/pen/QQQazg)